# Buy Mac Adress is necessary?

Tags: tcp, embedded, ethernet, mac-address

We're designing a custom device for our company. This device is communicating to other devices on ethernet protocol.

If we want to sell this device with random a mac ID, does it cause any troubles? Do we have to buy a company specific mac ID?

Comment: Do you mean a MAC address that already belongs to another company, or a MAC address with the "private" bit set that is only suitable for use in your private network?

Comment: Only suitable for our private network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you creating the MAC/PHY interface?
or are you using phy and communicating with it?
In that case, you dont need MAC Address

If you are creating all the communications, you may want to buy MAC for your device.
Just note that in some cases in your private network, that will not be a issue.

for more info https://standards.ieee.org/products-services/regauth/index.html